# Active Directory B2C and OpenIdConnectAuthenticationMiddleware - Multitenant systems

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory, azure-api-apps

I have set up two tenants, `123.onmicrosoft.com` and `abc.onmicrosoft.com`.

I have developed a web application using `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationMiddleware` to do the OpenID Connect authentication flow.

The out-of-the-box middleware requires the client ID to be passed during the configuration of the OWIN middleware, this is our challenge. Our web application is deployed once using two bindings: `123.mydomain.com` and `abc.mydomain.com`.

We want to set the client ID at runtime. Our current approach was to develop a subclass and inject a function to gather the client ID at runtime, something like this:

```cs
public class LendingMiddleware : OpenIdConnectAuthenticationMiddleware
{
    private Action<IOwinContext, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> _optionBuilder = null;
    public LendingMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next, IAppBuilder app,
        OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions options,
        Action<IOwinContext, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> optionBuilder = null) : base(next, app, options)
    {
        _optionBuilder = optionBuilder;
    }

    public LendingMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next, IAppBuilder app, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions options) : base(next, app, options)
    {
    }

    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        _optionBuilder?.Invoke(context, Options);
        await base.Invoke(context);
    }

}
```

On start up class we add two middleware: 
UseTenantVerification read the host header to load the application configuration associated to this tenant.
LendingAuthentication use LendingMiddleware to do the openid flow, lending Middleware inherid from OpenIdConnectAuthenticationMiddleware

```cs
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    //fixed address for multitenant apps in the public cloud
    string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/";

    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions { });
    app.UseTenantVerification();

    app.UseLendingAuthentication(CreateOptions(authority), (ctx, options) =>
    {
        TenantConfig tc = ctx.Environment["TenantInfo"] as TenantConfig;
        options.ClientId = tc.ClientId;
        options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudience = tc.ClientId;
        //ctx.ProtocolMessage.Password = tenantConfig.Secret;
    });
}
```

`TenantConfig` looks like this:

```cs
public TenantConfig GetTenantConfig(string httpHost)
{
    IDictionary<string, TenantConfig> Tenants = new Dictionary<string, TenantConfig>();
    Tenants.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, TenantConfig>("123.local", new TenantConfig
    {
        ClientId = "90677fe0-412c-4625-8d45-f37c14ffb456",
        Secret = "[secret!]",
        HostName = "123.local",
        ApiResources = new Dictionary<string, ApiResourceConfig>
        {
            {
                "TodoWebApi", new ApiResourceConfig
                {
                    ResourceIdentifier = "https://123.onmicrosoft.com/TodoWebApiMT",
                    ResourceAddress = "http://TodoWebApiMT.local"
                }
            }
        }
    }));

    Tenants.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, TenantConfig>("abc.local", new TenantConfig
    {
        ClientId = "000309f7-ac34-4fb6-a833-ef7c664e0958",
        Secret = "[secret!]",
        HostName = "abc.local",
        ApiResources = new Dictionary<string, ApiResourceConfig>
        {
           {
                "TodoWebApi", new ApiResourceConfig
                {
                    ResourceIdentifier = "https://abc.onmicrosoft.com/TodoWebApiMT",
                    ResourceAddress = "http://TodoWebApiMT.local"
                }
            }
        }
    }));

    var k = Tenants.Keys.First(item => item.Equals(httpHost));
    return Tenants[k];
}
```

We keep the client ID, app key and the API resources that this tenant would want to access. We have only one API app for now but eventually it will be a few API apps that would be added to the tenant directory to grant access.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Is there any reason you're not simply developing an application that is formally a multi-tenant application? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-multitenant-openidconnect/

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret - I started looking into the sample. I created two B2C directories and Added the sample web app to each directory. Now I have a pair of keys per directory instead of only one as the sample. This is the challenge, the owin middleware require the client ID at configuration time but this is too early, we want at runtime to select the client id base on the domain name used to access the sample web application.

Comment: Apologies, I missed the fact that you were doing this for B2C directories. You can disregard my question, as the concept of multi-tenant applications (and thus, using the `/common` and a single `client_id`) doesn't apply for B2C.